# how to validate the input information of splitting screen is correct?

Tags: algorithm

Here is an instance:
screen size : `1024 * 768`

Each block regards as a rectangle.

Coordinate: `0, 0` denotes left-down while `512, 384` denotes right-up

```
block 1 : <0, 0, 512, 384>

block 2 : <0, 384, 512, 1024>

block 3 : <512, 0, 1024, 384>

block 4 : <512, 384, 1024, 768>
```

the case above is correct, but how I can testify wrong one like:

case 1 :

```
block 1 : <0, 0, 512, 384>

block 2 : <0, 384, 512, 1024>

block 3 : <512, 0, 1024, 384>

block 4 : <800, 384, 1024, 768>
```

case 2 :

```
block 1 : <0, 0, 512, 384>

block 2 : <0, 384, 512, 1024>

block 3 : <512, 0, 1024, 384>

block 4 : <256, 192, 768, 576>
```

case 3:

```
block 1 : <0, 0, 1024, 384>

block 2 : <0, 0, 1024, 384>

block 3 : <0, 384, 512, 1024>
```

case 4 :

```
block 1 : <0, 0, 1024, 384>

block 2 : <5, 5, 600, 300>

block 3 : <0, 384, 512, 1024>
```

How I can detect the user's wrong input including empty or repeat blocks.

This is my idea：

I will first calculate the sum of area of blocks. Before calculating, I wipe off the repeated information of each block

such as

```
block 1 : <0, 0, 1024, 384>
block 2 : <0, 0, 1024, 384>
block 3 : <0, 384, 512, 1024>
```

the sum would be `1024*384 + 512*(1024-384)` not `1024*384*2 + 512*(1024-384)`.

If the sum is not equal to `1024*768`, then the user input is invalid.
Otherwise, I will find out if there is empty block or repeated blocks.

If there are `n` blocks, each block can compare with the rest. But then time complexity would be `O(n^2)`, which considers low performance.

I wonder if there are better ways to achieve the algorithm.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the computer language you happen to be using.  Before writing any code, work this out on paper.  Once you do that, then write the program that follows what you have on paper.

Comment: i have delete the programming language. i agree it has nothing to do with the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify, consider 2 blocks only. There are 4 case of overlapping at total:

0.

```
╭───╮
│ 1╭+──╮
└──+┘0 │
   └───┘
```

`top-left vertex` of block 0 located within block 1

1.

```
╭───╮
│ 0╭+──╮
└──+┘1 │
   └───┘
```

`top-left vertex` of block 1 located within block 0

2.

```
   ╭───╮
╭──+╮1 │
│ 0└+──┘
└───┘
```

`top-right vertex` of block 0 located within block 1

3.

```
   ╭───╮
╭──+╮0 │
│ 1└+──┘
└───┘
```

`top-right vertex` of block 1 located within block 0

---

`bool locate_within(Point, Rectangle)` should be easy to implement,

then apply it to `bool overlap(RectangleAlpha, RectangleBeta)`.

Pseudocode：

```
n = Rectangle-Count
for i in [0..(n-2)]:
    for k in [(i+1)..(n-1)]:
        if overlap(Rectangle[i], Rectangle[k]):
            return False
return True
```

Note: `True` -> validated

Time complexity: `O(n^2)`